# Using linked lists to determine whether two words are anagrams in C language

Tags: c

I have a pointer to two linked lists w1 and w2. The algorithm I'm using is for each letter in w1 search w2 for it. If found, delete it in w2 and then move on to the next letter in w1. If all letters are found the function returns 1. If a letter is not found it's supposed to return 0. The code works if the words are anagrams. But if the words are of equal length but not anagrams it is not returning zero as intended.

```
int anagram(nodeptr w1,nodeptr w2){
    char key;
    int frog=1,n=0,r=0;
    nodeptr count1,count2,curr,prev=NULL;
    count1=w1;
    count2=w2;
    while(count1!=NULL){
        n++;
        count1=count1->next;
    }
    while(count2!=NULL){
        r++;
        count2=count2->next;
    }
    if(n!=r)
        frog=0;
    else {
        while(w1!=NULL) {
            key=w1->ch;
            prev=NULL;
            curr=w2;
            while(curr!=NULL&&key!=curr->ch){
                prev=curr;
                curr=curr->next;
            }
            if(key==curr->ch&&prev==NULL){
                w2=curr->next;
                free(curr);
            }
            else if(curr==NULL)
                frog=0;
            else{
                prev->next=curr->next;
                free(curr);
            }
      
            w1=w1->next;
        }
    }

    return frog;
}
```

Comment: Why is the return value named `frog`?

Comment: I like amphibians so that word just popped in my head.

Comment: You need to test `if(curr==NULL)` before `if(key==curr->ch&&prev==NULL)` so you don't dereference a null pointer.

Comment: When you set frog to 0 you should break out of the loop. Or just do `return 0;` immediately, there's no need for `frog`.

Comment: OK thanks a million I'll try those suggestions

Comment: You should also break out of the loop when you find a match and remove it from `w2`. Otherwise you'll get wrong results when there are duplicate letters in `w2`, since it will remove all of them.

Comment: I'm not sure which of these are causing your problem.

Comment: Use strings instead, sort them, and `strcmp()` to see if they're equal.

Comment: OK I tried the suggestions. The problem was I needed to test if(curr==NULL) before if(key==curr->ch&&prev==NULL). I was dereferencing a null pointer. Thanks

Comment: Find a man a bug and you have saved his day. Teach a man to use a debugger and you have saved his life.